# Validation across four columns

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I have four columns and I need to restrict data from one column to another. If I type "dog" in any one column (row from that column) I want to restrict the same word on the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose validation options from the toolbar Data => Validation.  From this menu you can choose options to restrict the data entered in the cells.